# Check if you are in a Cell from a ContentControl which is in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

[image]

I have a problem.(again now with code) 
So, when I am in a cell then I gonna make a function that highlights it(cellColor()) and when I am in a ContenControl I also have a function which highlights(toggleYellow) it. 
So there is a simple If-function.(checkTableCC), which looks if you are in a ContentControl or in a Cell. So there is no problem.

But when there is a table and in that table there is **ContentControl** and in the ContentControl there is again a new **table** the If-Function does not work when I want to highlight the **cell** of the table which is in the **ContentControl** and which is in another **table** and I get an error 4641 The HighlightColor statement is currently disabled. 
I tried some things out but I cannot get the double check of the function. Maybe someone can help.

Here is my code so far which I did with the help of you guys. Thank you again:

```
'CC function
Function IsSelectionInCC(sel As Word.Selection) As Word.ContentControl
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim nrCC As Long
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Dim InCC As Boolean

    InCC = False
    Set rng = sel.Range
    Set doc = rng.Parent
    rng.Start = rng.Document.Content.Start
    nrCC = rng.ContentControls.Count
    If nrCC > 0 Then
        If sel.InRange(doc.ContentControls(nrCC).Range) Then
            InCC = True
            Set cc = doc.ContentControls(nrCC)
        Else
            sel.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
            If Len(sel) = 0 Then
                InCC = True
                Set cc = doc.ContentControls(nrCC)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set IsSelectionInCC = cc
End Function

'Highlight ContentControl[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Sub toggleYellow()
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

    Set cc = IsSelectionInCC(Selection)
    If Not cc Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = cc.Range
        If rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight Then
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Else
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'Highlight cell
Sub cellColor()


Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    MsgBox "Nur in einer Tabelle funktioniert dieses Makro."
    Exit Sub
End If

If Selection.Cells(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight Then
    Selection.Cells(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Else
    Selection.Cells(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
End If

Exit Sub

End Sub

'Check If you are in a CC or in a Cell
Sub checkTableCC()

Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

Set cc = IsSelectionInCC(Selection)
If Not cc Is Nothing Then
    toggleYellow
Else
    cellColor
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understood your specification. First of all, "when I'm in". Can you be specific about what that means? e.g. would collapsing the Selection to the start of selection tell you "what you are in" ? Second, you can have content controls within tables, tables within tables, etc. etc. If you're in a content control within a table and the table's within a content control and that's within a table, what highlighting do you want? See what I mean?

Comment: Yes sure. Thanks for answering me. With "I am in" I mean when the cursor is in the cell or in the ContentControl. So in the picture you see a table **"this is a test"** and in that cell of that table is a ContenControl and in that ContentControl is again a table and I want to highlight the cell of the table where **"Hey"** stands but then I get the error-message because of the nesting situation.

Comment: The situation for reproducing/testing is still unclear. *Where exactly* is the selection when the error appears? Which line of code causes the error? Are you able to highlight *manually*? If not, VBA cannot do it. Likely, it's a question of exactly where the selection is.

Comment: This is a pretty difficult question. Content controls can contain tables, table cells, or table rows. Table cells can contain content controls. The selection in content controls behaves differently depending on whether the control is showing a placeholder or not. So either you want to cope with *every possible situation that could exist within Word* (could anyone?!) or you have a subset of possible situations in mind. Which is why I asked if you could try to pin down the specification. Perhaps in your scenario placeholders are not an issue, or couldn't contain tables, for example.

Comment: _The situation for reproducing/testing is still unclear. Where exactly is the selection when the error appears?_

The error appears here:
`Selection.Cells(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen`

_Are you able to highlight manually?_
Yes of course I just want to highlight the **hey**

Comment: "subset of possible situations in mind"-> Yes I have in my mind do highlight this one:   From the **table** -> there is a **ContentControl** -> there is a **Cell**
-> and that Cell I want to highlight.

Comment: From my own experiences Range.HighlightColorIndex does not work when Range is in a table AND the cell text includes a paragraph marker (vbCr). Tried Range and Selection but both fail. Setting font color works fine so this 'behaviour' is limited to highlighting. Manual highlighting works fine which to me makes this a 'bug'.